# Why can't I pip install the latest version of fabric?

Tags: python, pip, fabric

I'm using a requirements file that lists all packages to install as part of my virtual env. One of these is `Fabric=1.10.2`, the most recent release. However, this fails to match:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   fabric==1.10.2 (from -r stable-req.txt (line 4)) (from versions:
>   0.0.1.macosx-10.4-i386, 0.0.2.macosx-10.4-i386, 0.0.3.macosx-10.4-i386, 0.0.4.macosx-10.4-i386, 0.0.5.macosx-10.4-i386, 0.0.1, 0.0.2, 0.0.3, 0.0.4, 0.0.5, 0.0.6, 0.0.7, 0.0.8, 0.0.9, 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.9.4, 0.9.5, 0.9.6, 0.9.7, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.4, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 0.0.1.macosx-10.4-i386, 0.0.2.macosx-10.4-i386, 0.0.3.macosx-10.4-i386, 0.0.4.macosx-10.4-i386, 0.0.5.macosx-10.4-i386, 0.0.1, 0.0.2, 0.0.3, 0.0.4, 0.0.5, 0.0.6, 0.0.7, 0.0.8, 0.0.9, 0.1.0, 0.1.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.9.4, 0.9.5, 0.9.6, 0.9.7, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.5, 1.1.6, 1.1.7, 1.1.8, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.4, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.8.3, 1.8.4, 1.8.5, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2) No distributions matching the version for fabric==1.10.2 (from -r stable-req.txt (line > 4))

Am I stuck with `1.10.1` until this has been propped somewhere? Is there a way I can initiate that prop, or whatever needs to happen? I'm not too well versed in how this works behind the scenes, so any insight would be super.

### Update 1

To address the comments and answers provided, calling `upgrade` isn't really an option, because we want to explicitly upgrade to `1.10.2`, which just happens to be the latest release at the moment. Once `1.10.3` is released, we don't want our scripts to auto-update our clients with this version until we tell it to do so.

Comment: have you tried upgrading? or not using pip and building from source

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
pip uninstall fabric
pip install fabric==1.10.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you can try to install it via commit id.

I think the commit you want is:
https://github.com/fabric/fabric/commit/c5065944e7f274cbd5b97c248681f89705972b3a

So you can try the following command:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/fabric/fabric.git@c5065944e7f274cbd5b97c248681f89705972b3a
```

PS: this not solve the problem (installing via version 1.10.2) but you might be able to install to work with the same code base of version you need.

Hope it helps! =)

Answer (score -1):

Latest version will be installed with

```
pip install django
```

Comment: What if you want `fabric` but not `django`?